# Modify each value of a dictionary to contain a child value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Let's say I have a dictionary called `packages` in an Ansible playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Question
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    package_key: "ubuntu"
    packages:
        openssh-server:
            archlinux:
                - pkg1
                - pkg2
            ubuntu:
                - pkg3
        cowsay:
            archlinux:
                - pkg4
        app-armor:
            archlinux:
                - pkg5
            ubuntu:
                - pkg6
                - pkg7
  tasks:
    - name: Transformation
      debug:
        msg={{ packages | dict2items | <something> | items2dict }}
```

If I know the `package_key` to be `ubuntu` on such a system, I would like to transform the dictionary so that I get:

```yaml
    transformed_packages:
        openssh-server:
            - pkg3
        app-armor:
            - pkg6
            - pkg7
```

What `<something>` do I need for this transformation? (Where the ubuntu packages are children of the applications, and when there is no ubuntu package, it's not part of the transformed dict).

My reason for this transformation is that I find it more convenient to group per app when I edit what packages are needed for different distros. But at the same time, it's more convenient to just keep what I need when I know the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of all packages

```yaml
  package_key: ubuntu
  pkg_attr: "value.{{ package_key }}"
  pkg_all: "{{ dict(packages.keys()|
                    zip(packages|
                        dict2items|
                        map(attribute=pkg_attr, default=[]))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  pkg_all:
    app-armor: [pkg6, pkg7]
    cowsay: []
    openssh-server: [pkg3]
```

---

Optionally, you can use *json_query*

```yaml
  pkg_query: '[].[key, {{ pkg_attr }}]'
  pkg_all: "{{ dict(packages|dict2items|json_query(pkg_query)) }}"
```

---

Select non-empty lists

```yaml
  transformed_packages: "{{ pkg_all|
                            dict2items|
                            selectattr('value')|
                            items2dict }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  transformed_packages:
    app-armor: [pkg6, pkg7]
    openssh-server: [pkg3]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    package_key: ubuntu
    packages:
      app-armor:
        archlinux: [pkg5]
        ubuntu: [pkg6, pkg7]
      cowsay:
        archlinux: [pkg4]
      openssh-server:
        archlinux: [pkg1, pkg2]
        ubuntu: [pkg3]

    pkg_attr: "value.{{ package_key }}"
    pkg_all: "{{ dict(packages.keys()|
                      zip(packages|
                          dict2items|
                          map(attribute=pkg_attr, default=[]))) }}"
    transformed_packages: "{{ pkg_all|
                              dict2items|
                              selectattr('value')|
                              items2dict }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: pkg_all|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: transformed_packages|to_yaml
```

---

You can make the declaration more robust if you don't trust the method *keys()* and the filter *dict2items* provides the same order of keys

```yaml
  pkg_all: "{{ dict(packages|
                    dict2items|
                    map(attribute='key')|
                    zip(packages|
                        dict2items|
                        map(attribute=pkg_attr, default=[]))) }}"
```

---

**Pros and Cons**

You can put options 1,2,3 into the [*vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and make the code of *tasks* easier readable

1. **json_query**

Pros: The most efficient option is *json_query*.
Cons: You have to install [*JmesPath*](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) and learn rather specific [syntax](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

```yaml
  pkg_attr: "value.{{ package_key }}"
  pkg_query: '[].[key, {{ pkg_attr }}]'
  pkg_all: "{{ dict(packages|dict2items|json_query(pkg_query)) }}"
  tp: "{{ pkg_all|dict2items|selectattr('value')|items2dict }}"
```

2. **Ansible and Jinja filters and functions**

Pros: Jinja is available by default. Cons: The pipe of [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html) and [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) filters, and [functions](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-globals.dict) is less efficient

```yaml
  pkg_attr: "value.{{ package_key }}"
  pkg_all: "{{ dict(packages.keys()|
                    zip(packages|
                        dict2items|
                        map(attribute=pkg_attr, default=[]))) }}"
  tp: "{{ pkg_all|dict2items|selectattr('value')|items2dict }}"
```

3. **Jinja template**

Pros: This option is always available. You can use it when Ansible and Jinja functions, filters, and tests can't solve the use case without iteration. Cons: Because of the iteration the efficiency is the worst of all options

```yaml
  tp: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k,v in packages.items() %}
      {% if package_key in v %}
      {{ k }}: {{ v[package_key] }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

4. **Iteration in set_fact task**

All pros and cons of 3. apply here with one more Con: You make the tasks more complex. The code is easier to read when the declarations of variables are 'hidden' in *vars*

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      tp: "{{ tp|default({})|
              combine({item.key: item.value[package_key]}) }}"
    loop: "{{ packages|
              dict2items |
              selectattr('value.' + package_key, 'defined') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Very nice answer! I came up with an alternative solution, and I would be glad to learn what pros and cons you see with the different ways of solving it.

Comment: I added the pros and cons section. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

One way to transform the packages dictionary is by using a `loop` and `combine`:

```
---
- name: Question
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
      package_key: "ubuntu"
      packages:
          openssh-server:
              archlinux:
                  - pkg1
                  - pkg2
              ubuntu:
                  - pkg3
          cowsay:
              archlinux:
                  - pkg4
          app-armor:
              archlinux:
                  - pkg5
              ubuntu:
                  - pkg6
                  - pkg7
  tasks:
      - set_fact:
            transformed_packages: "{{ transformed_packages |
                default({}) |
                combine({item.key:item.value[package_key]}) }}"
        loop: "{{ packages |
            dict2items |
            selectattr('value.' + package_key, 'defined') }}"
      - debug:
            msg: "{{ transformed_packages }}"
```